# Does ns3 support 3d topology?

Tags: ns-3

I'm using ns3 to simulate a wireless data center. I started it with 2d topology using "GridPositionAllocator".

```
    MobilityHelper mobility;
    mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
    "MinX", DoubleValue (0.0),
    "MinY", DoubleValue (0.0),
    "DeltaX", DoubleValue (1.0),
    "DeltaY", DoubleValue (1.0),
    "GridWidth", UintegerValue (8),
    "LayoutType", StringValue ("ColumnFirst"));
    mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
    mobility.Install (wifiNodes);
```

How could I change it to 3d to place several servers in a rack?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, ns-3 does support 3D mobility since the mobility vectors are 3D (X, Y, Z), however there is no 'PositionAllocator' implemented for that. Contributions are welcome.

A simple solution is to extend this GridPositionAllocator which assumes Z=0 and add the 3rd dimension with corresponding MinZ, DeltaZ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but adding a 3d topology with grid position allocator is not possible.
You could use a ListPostionAllocator to manually specify the positions of all the nodes.

You could use the following:

```
Ptr<ListPostionAllocator> lp =CreateObject<ListPostionAllocator>();
//Adding locations of 2 nodes 
lp->ADD(Vector (10.0,10.0,10.0);
lp->ADD(Vector (20.0,20.0,20.0);  //Add locations of all the nodes 
mobHelper.SetpostionAllocator(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
We can use Gauss-Markov 3D Mobility Model Under ns-3 for Simulating 3D Network.

[Using Gauss-Markov 3D Mobility Model Under ns-3 for Simulating Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV), Aerial Ad-hoc Network (AANET) and Flying Ad-hoc Network (FANET)](https://www.projectguideline.com/using-gauss-markov-3d-mobility-model-under-ns-3-for-simulating-unmanned-aerial-vehicle-uav-aerial-ad-hoc-network-aanet-and-flying-ad-hoc-network-fanet/)